# change json dynamically from parameters

Tags: javascript, json

I want to create a json object according to function parameters but it takes the parameters as a string.

```
userSchema.statics.updated = async function (_id, field, value) { // it does not take that params
  const user = await this.updateOne({ _id }, { $set: { field: value } }); //!!!!
};
```

The field parameters is a json field that i create like name,age... But it always create and object like

```
{"field":value}
```

how can i fix it?

Json structure example:

```
{
        "email": "",
        "password": "",
        "surname": "",
        "name": "",
        "nickname": "",
        "birthdate": ""
    }
```

Comment: What you're looking for is `{ [field]: value }`if I understand correctly. The key must be dynamic, but right now you're marking it explicitly as `field`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the string "field" as the value field, Try pass a real field name, for example:

```
const jsonFile = require('jsonFile');
const object = JSON.parse(jsonFile);
fieldName = 'email';
userSchema.statics.updated(_id, object[fieldName], false));

// You can also:

const keys = Object.keys(object);
userSchema.statics.updated(_id, object[keys[0]], false));
```